# Validation to allow single space for phone numbers

Tags: .net, asp.net, regex, requiredfieldvalidator

i have a validation in my .net textbox where it will take only numbers

but when i put the the phone format like

080 234234

it will not accept because of a space

how to resolve this ?

could anyone help in regular expression ?

Current expression is this [0-9]+

i want only single space ... no two spaces should be encoraged

Comment: Do you mean "no two consecutive spaces", i.e. NOT "123  234"? Or do you mean "at most one space in the whole number, i.e. NOT "123 234 345"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[0-9]+\s?[0-9]+
```

The question mark indicates there is *zero or one* of the preceding element.

Answer (score 1):

This will allow a single white space after the first three digits:
[0-9]{3}\s?[0-9]{6}

This would allow white spaces (only one in a row) anywhere: ([0-9]\s?)+

Answer (score 1):

\s gives one space. Maybe something like this: `[0-9]{3}\s?[0-9]{6}`
This means it'll take three digitis followed by an optional whitespace character and ending with six digits.

Answer (score 0):

something like this:
([0-9]{1}[0-9]*[\s]{0,1}[0-9])+([\s]{0,1}[0-9]+)

**UPDATE:**
the benefit of this method is that it won't allow leading or trailing spaces, and of course enforces single spaces.